# Is every set a filtered colimit of finite sets?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, limits-colimits

Is the following statement correct in the category of sets?

> Let $X$ be any set. Then there exists a filtered small category $I$ and a functor $F:I\to \mathrm{Set}$ such that for all $i\in I$ the set $F(i)$ is finite, and such that
>   $$
> X \; = \; \mathrm{colim}_{i\in I} F(i) .
> $$

Are there references on results of this type in the literature?

Comment: One way to generalize this is the notion of a [locally finitely presentable category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+finitely+presentable+category).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is yes: every set is the union of its finite subsets.

So take $I = P_{\text{finite}}(X)$ with as morphisms the inclusion maps, and $F : I \to \text{Set}$ the inclusion.

Answer (score 10):

One answer already mentions the diagram of finite subsets of $X$. You would have to check that taking the union of this system actually is the colimit (which is an easy exercise).

Since you asked for a reference, *Locally Presentable and Accessible Categories* by J. Adámek and J. Rosický is a great book on this kind of stuff. In particular example 1.2(1) already mentions the diagram of finite subsets.